# How to Animate the fill attribute of inline SVG on mouseover/mouseout (SMIL)

Tags: animation, svg, hover, mouseover, smil

I have created a simple inline SVG.

Using SMIL I have tried to animate the `fill` attribute to pink for all paths upon `mouseover` of the parent SVG `id`.

On `mouseout` I would like the `fill` to **always** reset.

I **do not** want the `fill` animation to repeat on `mouseover`. I just want it to run once and 'stop' (i.e. stay pink), but, **only** if the animation duration completes.

I have tried the following:

```css
#logoSVG {
    width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="logo">
  <svg version="1.1" id="logoSVG" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 113.7 62.2" enable-background="new 0 0 113.7 62.2" xml:space="preserve">
    <path id="M" fill="#1E90FF" d="M16.1,38.9l-9-30.4H6.7C7.2,14.8,7.2,18.8,7.2,21v17.9H0V0h11.2l9,29.5l0,0L30,0h11.2v38.5h-7.6
    V20.6c0-0.9,0-1.8,0-3.1c0-1.3,0-4,0.4-9h-0.4l-9.8,30.4L16.1,38.9L16.1,38.9z" />
    <path id="A" fill="#1E90FF" d="M74.7,38.9l-2.7-9.4H58.2l-2.7,9.4h-9L60,0h9.8l13.9,38.9H74.7z M69.8,22.8c-2.7-8.5-4-13-4.5-14.3
    c-0.4-0.9-0.4-1.8-0.9-2.7c-0.4,2.2-2.2,7.6-4.9,16.6h10.3V22.8z" />
    <path id="T" fill="#1E90FF" d="M102.9,38.9h-8.1V7.2H84.6V0h29.1v6.7h-10.3v32.2H102.9z" />
    <rect id="Line" y="55.9" fill="#1E90FF" width="113.7" height="6.3" />

    <animate xlink:href="#M" attributeName="fill" from="#1E90FF" to="pink" dur="0.8s" begin="logoSVG.mouseover" end="logoSVG.mouseout" id="m-anim" />
    <animate xlink:href="#A" attributeName="fill" from="#1E90FF" to="pink" dur="0.8s" begin="m-anim.begin + 0s" end="logoSVG.mouseout" id="a-anim" />
    <animate xlink:href="#T" attributeName="fill" from="#1E90FF" to="pink" dur="0.8s" begin="m-anim.begin + 0s" end="logoSVG.mouseout" id="t-anim" />
    <animate xlink:href="#Line" attributeName="fill" from="#1E90FF" to="pink" dur="0.8s" begin="m-anim.begin + 0s" end="logoSVG.mouseout" id="line-anim" />
  </svg>
</a>
```

As you can see the `fill` does not 'stop' at the end.

Am I missing something?
Is `mouseover`/`mouseout` the right value to use to achieve this effect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a "fill" attribute to your -Tags, and set it to "freeze", e.g.:

```
<animate xlink:href="#M" attributeName="fill" from="#1E90FF"
  to="pink" dur="0.8s" begin="logoSVG.mouseover" 
  end="logoSVG.mouseout" id="m-anim" fill="freeze"/>
```

[From the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/fill):

> freeze -  The animation effect is "frozen" when the active duration of the animation is over for the remainder of the document duration (or until the animation is restarted).

**Update**

If mouse events are triggered correctly, the freezed fill wont change back.

Alternatively, you could animate each state explicitly:

1. change the color
2. keep the filling
3. change the fill back to the original color

I reduced the example to just one letter, for clarity:

```css
#logoSVG {
    border: 1px dashed #777;
    width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0)" id="logo">
  <svg version="1.1" id="logoSVG" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 113.7 62.2" enable-background="new 0 0 113.7 62.2" xml:space="preserve">
    <path id="M" fill="#1E90FF" d="M16.1,38.9l-9-30.4H6.7C7.2,14.8,7.2,18.8,7.2,21v17.9H0V0h11.2l9,29.5l0,0L30,0h11.2v38.5h-7.6
    V20.6c0-0.9,0-1.8,0-3.1c0-1.3,0-4,0.4-9h-0.4l-9.8,30.4L16.1,38.9L16.1,38.9z" />

    <animate xlink:href="#M" attributeName="fill" from="#1E90FF" to="pink" dur="0.8s" begin="logoSVG.mouseover" end="logoSVG.mouseout" id="m-anim" fill="freeze"/>
    <animate xlink:href="#M" attributeName="fill" from="pink" to="pink" dur="0.8s" begin="logoSVG.mouseover+0.8s" end="logoSVG.mouseout" id="m-anim" fill="freeze"/>
    <animate xlink:href="#M" attributeName="fill" from="#1E90FF" to="#1E90FF" begin="logoSVG.mouseout" end="logoSVG.mouseover" id="m-anim" fill="freeze"/>

  </svg>
</a>
```

A sidenote: begin values like begin="m-anim.begin + 0s" seem not work in Firefox (Developer Edition 41.0a2 (2015-07-18), at least on my machine

Comment: Thanks for that - it solves any repeating issues, but adding this attribute prevents this from happening... "On mouseout I would like the fill to always reset."?

Comment: Sorry, I did not realize that - maybe i moved my mouse to fast

Comment: I updated my answer to use another, more explizit approach: use 1 animation tag for each desired state. The first to change the color, one to keep the filling and the last one to change the fill back to the original color.